# Why there is unused-but-set variable-warning with pointers

Tags: c++11, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    
    Test(int i) {
        initialize(i);
    }
    
    void initialize(int i) {
        std::cout<<"i: "<<i<<std::endl;
    }
};



int main() {
    Test* obj1(nullptr);
    obj1 = new Test(2);
    
    Test* obj2(nullptr);
    obj2 = new Test(2);
    obj2->initialize(3);    
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile as such (GCC v11.2.0):

```
g++ -Wall --std=c++11 main.cpp
```

I see the following warning:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:25:15: warning: variable ‘obj1’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   25 |         Test* obj1(nullptr);
      |               ^~~~
```

**My question is why is there a warning for obj1, but not obj2 when they do almost the same thing?**

Comment: Because you do actually use `obj2` in the line `obj2->initialize(3);`

Comment: You use `obj2` after initilization unlike `obj1`

Comment: obj1 also calls the initialize function, but only in the ctor.  Why is this considered insufficient for -Wall flag?

Comment: It doesn't matter what your object does in its constructor, the analyzer is complaining about you creating a variable that you only assign but never use otherwise

Comment: `obj1` does not call the initialize function -- the initialize function is called by the ctor of the unnamed object that later has it's address stored in `obj1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to realize here is that you actually have FOUR objects in your code -- two instances of the class `Test` and two pointers.  The instances of `Test` don't have names (they're created with `new`), while the pointers do have names (`obj1` and `obj2`).

The warning here is about the pointer object `obj1` which is only ever assigned to and not used.  The fact that the object it points at after the final assignment has had various side effects prior to that assignment is not relevant.  You could remove the declaration an assignment (but not the new call in the assignment) without affecting the behavior or output of your program.

```
int main() {
    new Test(2);
    
    Test* obj2(nullptr);
    obj2 = new Test(2);
    obj2->initialize(3);    
    
    return 0;
}
```